# C# Application doesn't seem to run on a similar computer to mine

Tags: c#, windows, compatibility, requirements

Unfortunately I haven't quite found the awnser I was looking for in the search section or any other coding forums so I'll leave my question here hopping for some closure.

I've developed a very simple C# Application , one of Windows' startup projects - the maze one, which uses a simple panel with labels and simple mouse events to trigger the placement of the pointer's position back to start.

I have succesfully published my application and it works smoothly on my computer and a few others but for some weird reason it simply won't load on my friend's laptop.

We both share the same OS (Windows 7), we both have the x64 version and the framework seems to be the same, but even though the process is displayed in the task manager, it simply won't load, even after the installation is successful.

So , the program does run but it seems like it won't load and it does not throw any exceptions or errors to be analyzed.

Therefore my question is, what are the requirements for my programs to be fully compatible with other computers ?

I appreciate the attention , I've spent a lot of time working on this matter and can't seem to find the correct awnser.

I will also display my form code for further analysis:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Labirinto
    {
        public partial class frmLabirinto : Form
        {
            // Toca um som sempre que o utilizador bater numa parede
            System.Media.SoundPlayer startSoundPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Ricardo Borges\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Labirinto\Labirinto\Resources\doh.wav");
            // Toca um som sempre que o utilizador chegar ao final do labirinto
            System.Media.SoundPlayer finishSoundPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Ricardo Borges\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Labirinto\Labirinto\Resources\tada.wav");


    public frmLabirinto()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MoveToStart();
    }

    private void frmLabirinto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// O método permite que o ponteiro do rato volte ao ponto inicial
    /// </summary>
    private void MoveToStart()
    {
        startSoundPlayer.Play(); //Toca o som de reinicio do jogo
        Point startingPoint = panel1.Location; //ponto inicial
        startingPoint.Offset(10, 10); //localizacao do ponto inicial
        Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(startingPoint); //coloca o cursor no local inicial
    }

    private void finishLabel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        finishSoundPlayer.Play(); //Toca o som de fim de jogo
        // Congratula o utilizador através de uma mensagem no ecrã
        MessageBox.Show("Parabéns, encontrou a saída do labirinto");
        Close();
    }

    private void wall_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MoveToStart(); //recoloca o ponteiro no ponto inicial ao embater numa parede
    }


}
```

}

Comment: how can the values of the startSoundPlayer and finishSoundPlayer be hardcoded.. make sure the files are present on ur friends system.

Comment: @Parv: +1.  I didn't even check the code!

Comment: Well if the program is compiled into an exe is that strictly necessary? And how should I add the reference in a more proper way then?

Comment: "Well if the program is compiled into an exe is that strictly necessary" - that comment does not make sense. If the path is not present on a machine then of course you need to parameterise it, or compile any resources into your executable.

Comment: Have you checked the event viewer on the affected machine to see if it has an entry based on the application failure?

Comment: As it is obvious, I'm still starting on C# and I've had successful programs working ON MY COMPUTER, but haven't tried carrying those to other computers . This is my first try, hence the hard time in actually getting those players to work with the files.
And Jamie , I did have a log there but for some reason I couldn't get it to work on neither of the pc's.

Comment: @vuk77, the `event viewer` Jamie mentioned is part of Windows. On Win7, `Start->Control Panel->System and Security->Administrative Tools->View Event Logs`. They exist on all machines running Windows, and you can't control whether they work on the PC; they're part of the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that the hard coded values used when initialising both of the SoundPlayer objects is causing an error. As an example what if there isn't a user under the name "Ricardo Borges" on the machine that is running the application?

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer startSoundPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Ricardo Borges\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Labirinto\Labirinto\Resources\doh.wav"); 
System.Media.SoundPlayer finishSoundPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\Ricardo Borges\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Labirinto\Labirinto\Resources\tada.wav");
```

[Based on the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143771.aspx) for the SoundPlayer object **'if the path or URL is not valid, the SoundPlayer will still be constructed, but subsequent calls to a load or play method will fail'.**

The first line within the MoveToStart function has the following line:

```
startSoundPlayer.Play();
```

Referring back to MSDN for the [SoundPlayer.Play](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.play.aspx) method it can throw one of three different exceptions depending on the cause of the error - the **FileNotFoundException** seems to be a likely culprit.

Can you confirm that both the specified locations and the actual files exist on the machine having problems?

Comment: No but what actually gets me confused is that the same build has worked for other machines, which wouldn't have the same path as well. But I understand all of your points and I appreciate the effort. How can I actually replace that reference so it gets carried on with the rest of the files needed on the project when it gets published/built ?

Comment: @vuk77 You need to add some logging (System.Diagnostics) to the application, particular in the area where it loads and initialises data. If you can capture an error then it will help us to narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Fusion Log viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to diagnose any assembly load errors?

[Using Fusion Log Viewer to Debug Obscure Loader Errors](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx)

If that's not the problem, add logging code to your application, and check your code for any try/catch blocks that are 'swallowing' errors.